# How to fix Invalid Operands to Binary Expression with Strings?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a binary Search function that will be used a lot for my project, when running my code I get an error saying:

> In file included from main.cpp:8:
>   In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
>   In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
>   In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
>   In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string:477:
>   In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:176:
>   In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:56:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:719:71:
>
> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Land' and 'const Land')
>       bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x < __y;}

Here is my Function:

```
long int CLandRegister::binarySearch(vector<Land> lands, Land l, size_t unsortedStart){
    long int val = lower_bound(lands.begin(), lands.begin()+unsortedStart-1, l)-lands.begin();
    if(lands[val].city == l.city && lands[val].addr == l.addr &&
       lands[val].region == l.region && lands[val].id == l.id){
           return val;
       }
    for(size_t i = unsortedStart-1; i < lands.size(); i++){
       if(lands[i].city == l.city && lands[i].addr == l.addr &&
       lands[i].region == l.region && lands[i].id == l.id){
           return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

City, addr and region are strings and id is an int.

At first I thought the problem was with the strings being compared to each other with a == sign because I am new to c++ and have been using c for a while now. So I replaced the == signs with std::compare and I thought it would do the trick. But it still fails.

Is it a problem with my system? I am on a mac, or Is there something I shouldn't be doing here?

I have been stuck on this part for a while now.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. 2) "_At first I thought the problem was with the strings being compared to each other with a == sign because I am new to c++_" In such cases, when one isn't certain about behavior, of standard classes, one might try to read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Comment: This code did not produce this error. Read the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `operator<` function between two `Land` objects. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

The part of the error message that gives the clue is the following expression

```
{ return __x < __y; }
         ^^^^^^^^^
```